# re allocate the Boot recovery partition space to the main system

Tags: hard-drive, partition

I am very new to apple, 
I tried look up answer but was afraid to mess thing up more and loose data so decided to ask for precise answer here.

I have hard drive on my mac of 750GB, and decided to divide it to 2 partitions, 450 and 300 but then I deleted the 300G but these 300 GB now have been added to the Apple Boot recovery HD and I can't use it.

I will attach a photo through the terminal.
Please let me know how can I reuse that space and add it to the main system hard drive.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd make a backup of your system and then format the partition altogether.

Comment: can I just merge them with orders through the terminal? instead of format?

Comment: You cant merge the boot recovery with the Mac partition. It's separate so that you can troubleshoot the mac if you need to reinstall it which is what I recommend.

Comment: Thanks Melvin for your help!  But is there a way to cut the size of the boot revovery into it's original size about 700MB-1GB, and then merge the remaining unallocated space with the main system.

Comment: Is there any way of resizing the boot recovery back down to something sensible, so I can reclaim the remaining extra space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a backup of your system and then format the partition altogether.

You cant merge the boot recovery with the Mac partition. It's separate so that you can troubleshoot the mac if you need to reinstall it which is what I recommend.

As for resizing the MacOS boot partition to a smaller size, you can try this fix from this question: https://superuser.com/a/985499/841637

> To fix:
>
> 1. Boot into the OS as normal.
> 2. Open a terminal.
> 3. Repair the disk `diskutil repairVolume /dev/disk0s3` (where disk0s3 is your volume)
> 4. Verify the disk `diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk0s3`
> 5. Resize the partition `diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s3 650M`
> 6. Boot into the recovery mode
> 7. Open the terminal, don't use the Disk Utility
> 8. Resize the actual disk `diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s2 200G` (where disk0s2 is the actual disk you want to resize, 200G is your
>      size)

Just make sure that your drive volume names are in place of the volumes inserted in the list above.

See if you are able to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much! The first part was extremely helpful to resize the boot recovery to small size, then I ended up with un allocated 300GB. but I couldn't do it as you said (from point 6-8 above) but I did it through normal boot and using the disk utility, where I deleted the un allocated space and it added it to my logical volume and now I have all the 750 GB as my main system storage and I can access it all. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that you were able to get that sorted out.